# List String within a class

Tags: c#, list

I have a class with several `public accessor`, of which one is a `List<String> p {get; set;}`

my question is, this:

in the code that instantiates this class, i'm looping through a string which can contain many lines of p, therefore for each line of p i want to add it to the `List<String> p`

So i've tried this:

```
  instancenam.p.AddRange(string.Split(new char[] {':',':'})[2]);
```

which gets me the second set of values in a string comprise like `:23A:TETCGR`

when i run the code i get the following two errors:

---

**Error 1:**

*The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List.AddRange(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable)' has some invalid arguments*

---

**Error 2:**

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'*

---

I've googled, but get confused with the responses ;-)

foreach (string str in lines)
                {
                    // Need to check that the length is greater than 3.
                    if (str != "4:" && str != " ")
                    {
                        // Store the tag name

```
                    if (str.StartsWith(":"))
                    {
                        tag = str.Split(new char[] { ':', ':' })[1];

                        SavedTag = tag;

                        switch (MessageType)
                        {

                                // Tag 13C Time Indication
                                if (tag == "13C")
                                {
                                    mt202.tag13C.Add(str.Split(new char[] { ':', ':' })[2]);
                                } 
                                break;
                        }
```

Ok, so named as recommend i now have the following. where my string contains multiple tag :13C:

using the above Add i get object reference not set to an instance of an object

EDIT:

```
    public class MT202
    {
        public string tag20 { get; set; }
        public string tag21 { get; set; }
        public List<String> tag13C { get; set; }
        public string tag32A { get; set; }
        public string tag33B { get; set; }
     }

 // Code below is from the calling class
     if (tag == "13C")
                               {
                                    char[] delimiters = new char[] { ':', ':' };
                                    string[] splitValues = str.Split(delimiters);
                                    string singleValue = splitValues[2];
                                    List<string> mt202.tag13C = new List<string>();
                                    mt202.tag13C.Add(singleValue);

                                  //  mt202.tag13C.Add(str.Split(new char[] { ':', ':' })[2]);
                                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break down this line:

```
instancenam.p.AddRange(string.Split(new char[] {':',':'})[2]);
```

I'm going to assume that the `string` part is actually the name of a variable (`string` isn't a valid identifier). I'll call it `text` below.

The expanded code looks like this:

```
char[] delimiters = new char[] {':',':'};
string[] splitValues = text.Split(delimiters);
string singleValue = splitValues[2];
List<string> list = instancenam.p;
list.AddRange(singleValue);
```

That will give the same error, because you're calling `AddRange` which is meant to take a *collection* of values - but you're only providing a *single* value. If you just want to add a single value, use `Add`:

```
instancenam.p.Add(text.Split(new char[] {':',':'})[2]);
```

I'd recommend breaking the code into something a *bit* more like the code above though - maybe not broken down quite that far, but at least a little bit. (You could have a readonly static field for the delimiters, for a start.)

Additionally, I'd strongly recommend you rename your property from `p` to something more meaningful, in PascalCase to conform to .NET naming conventions.

EDIT: Now the post has been edited with this:

> using the above Add i get object reference not set to an instance of an object

That suggests that either `mt202` or `mt202.tag13C` is a `null` reference, but we can't tell which. You should look into it with a debugger.

Comment: ok, so mt202.tag13C is null - i'm assuming this is because there hasn't yet been anything added to it.

Comment: @CSharpNewBee: No, there's nothing to add to - there's no list yet. You're presumably never initializing the variable with code such as `tag13C = new List<string>();`

Comment: Morning Jon, i've made an edit above, which includes the class and what I believe to be the method you've just described

Comment: @CSharpNewBee: In future, it's worth only adding the comment saying "I've made an edit above" after you've actually done so. Will look now.

Comment: @CSharpNewBee: You're now trying to declare a new local variable called `mt202.tag13C`. That's not going to work, and you probably *don't* want to change it to a new list anyway. I'm afraid there isn't really enough context to help you, but you should take a step back - don't just try to add one line here or there, but really think about where you want to initialize the list. Do you even need callers to be able to set it to a new list? Perhaps you should only have a getter, but initialize it within the MT202 class itself.

Comment: Jon, i see the error in my ways now. Many thanks. I've declared the List as a new list in the class, then add to it when required.